# Does the Java &= operator apply & or &&?

Tags: java, operators

Assuming

```
boolean a = false;
```

I was wondering if doing:

```
a &= b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a && b; //logical AND, a is false hence b is not evaluated.
```

or on the other hand it means

```
a = a & b; //Bitwise AND. Both a and b are evaluated.
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification - [15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2).

> *A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.*

So `a &= b;` is equivalent to `a = a & b;`.

(In some usages, the type-casting makes a difference to the result, but in this one `b` has to be `boolean` and the type-cast does nothing.)

And, for the record, `a &&= b;` is not valid Java.  There is no `&&=` operator.

---

In practice, there is little semantic difference between `a = a & b;` and `a = a && b;`.  (If `b` is a variable or a constant, the result is going to be the same for both versions.  There is only a semantic difference when `b` is a subexpression that has side-effects.  In the `&` case, the side-effect always occurs.  In the `&&` case it occurs depending on the value of `a`.)

On the performance side, the trade-off is between the cost of evaluating `b`, and the cost of a test and branch of the value of `a`, and the potential saving of avoiding an unnecessary assignment to `a`.  The analysis is not straight-forward, but unless the cost of calculating `b` is non-trivial, the  performance difference between the two versions is too small to be worth considering.

Comment: Hallelujah for the performance comments.  I habitually run into code-reviewers who want me to write `x = y && x` instead of `x = y & z`, for simple boolean variables.

Comment: Note: a potential use-case of `&=` is if you are iterating through a for loop with a "result" variable set to true by default, and wanted to set it to false if at any point during the for loop what you are evaluating is false, while also preventing it from being reset back to true once it is false for the first time.

Comment: So, I know this is over a decade old now, but I'm brushing up on my java, and I just ran into a "well technically ..." situation wrt this.  Actually somewhat related to @Collin's comment.  If you are evaluating `a&=booleanMethod()`, it is not strictly equivalent to `a=a&&booleanMethod()`, because if `a==false`, it won't evaluate `booleanMethod`.   So you'd have to do `a=booleanMethod() && a`.

Comment: @MiaoLiu - That is what this is saying:  *"There is only a semantic difference when `b` is a subexpression that has side-effects. In the `&` case, the side-effect always occurs. In the `&&` case it occurs depending on the value of `a`."*   The "*subexpression `b`*" would be a call to your `booleanMethod`.  (If `booleanMethod` doesn't have any side-effects then this is moot; i.e. no difference at all between `&` and `&&` from a semantic perspective.)

Answer (score 54):

see [15.22.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).  For boolean operands, the `&` operator is boolean, not bitwise.  The only difference between `&&` and `&` for boolean operands is that for `&&` it is short circuited (meaning that the second operand isn't evaluated if the first operand evaluates to false).

So in your case, if `b` is a primitive, `a = a && b`, `a = a & b`, and `a &= b` all do the same thing.

Comment: So (a &= b;) will not short-circuit if b is a method call? is there something like a "&&=" operator?

Comment: It seems that this doesn't answer the question; the OP already knew about short-circuiting.

Answer (score 27):

It's the last one:

```
a = a & b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to test it:

```
public class OperatorTest {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a = false;
        a &= b();
    }

    private static boolean b() {
        System.out.println("b() was called");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output is `b() was called`, therefore the right-hand operand is evaluated.

So, as already mentioned by others,  `a &= b` is the same as `a = a & b`.

Comment: Why do we need to test it when the JLS plainly states what the behavior it?  Reading the spec or a good book or tutorial or some other authoritative source is much better (and safer) than programming by trial and error.

Comment: @StephenC it is just another strategy to find an answer to such a question. I wouldn't call this programming by trial and error. Reading the JLS is good, but having another strategy at hand can't hurt.

Comment: Well yea ... but the problem with the "why don't you just test it" approach is that people 1) misinterpret the results of the test ... or unwittingly test the wrong thing, and 2) don't bother to read the JLS (or whatever) to validate their testing.  And then they end up with incorrect "knowledge" which comes back to bite them and their coworkers.

Answer (score -5):

i came across a similar situation using booleans where I wanted to avoid calling b() if a was already false.

This worked for me:

```
a &= a && b()
```

Comment: In order to avoid redundancies (still allowing for short-circuiting), you can simply write `a=a&&b()`.