# Can someone explain what the following expression does in this program?

Tags: java, syntax

```
String convertByteToBase4(byte x) {
    String result = “";
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        result = "0123".charAt(x & 3) + result;
        x = (byte)(x>>2)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Im confused as to what the purpose of the &3 is in this code, is it supposed to add the short for 3 to the byte x?

Comment: Isn't it Bit-wise AND operation?

Comment: @ghuchoi, Yes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: It's called: bitwise AND: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907082/does-the-java-operator-apply-or

Answer (score 1):

You are converting to base 4, which means two bits for each digit.

3 is the binary 11, which is two bits.

& 3 is the bitwise and, which effectively isolates the rightmost two bits, or the rightmost base 4 digit.

This is coupled with >>2 which shifts the number two bits to the right.

The whole loop: gets the rightmost two bits, shifts two bits, gets the next two bits, shifts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator, but when the bitwise operand is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, `&`  is the same as `%` with the operand plus 1, ie, these two are the same (for positive `x`):

```
x & 3 // AND with 11
x % 4 // modulo 4
```

In your case, `& 3` (or `% 4`) only produces values between 0 and 3 inclusive (for positive `x`).

Answer (score 0):

```
"0123".charAt(x & 3)
```

`charAt` returns a character of the given string at the given index. In this case, the string is `"0123"` and the index is determined by `x & 3`.

`3` is `0000 0011` in binary. 2-bit binary number ranges `[0, 3]`; `00`, `01`, `10`, and `11`.

`x & 3` masks out higher bits in `x`:

```
  x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2 x1 x0
&  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
-------------------------
                    x1 x0
```

So you can simply think `x & 3` as `x % 4`. And, definitely, bit-wise operation is much faster than arithmetic operation.